# Telegraph availability in Russia around year 1875

Tags: russia, communication

Were there any telegraph lines available in late 19th century Russia (let's say year 1875), which would go deep into mainland Russia?

I can find some mentions about [Moscow telegraph station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Telegraph) being created in 1852 and then extended few times around 1870. I cannot find any specific reports of the lines going between the cities, but I suppose there is a good chance they would follow main railroad routes, especially to St Petersburg (back then capital of Russia).

What I'm really interested in are any connections going the other direction - east of Moscow.

There was a failed attempt to create [America->Moscow telegraph line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian%E2%80%93American_Telegraph) in 1860's, but it stopped well before reaching mainland Russia.

So, in 1875, was there any possibility of sending a message from Moscow or St Petersburg, to Tomsk, for example, faster than utilizing [snail mail](https://www.openbookpublishers.com/htmlreader/978-1-78374-373-5/ch5.xhtml)?

Comment: Wasn't snail mail faster then than now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it was possible to send a telegraph message from Moscow or St Petersburg to Tomsk in 1875. [Tomsk was connected in 1863, Irkutsk in 1864 and Omsk in or before 1866](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284886871_The_first_projects_and_the_commencement_of_installation_of_the_electric_telegraph_through_siberia_and_the_Russian_far_east_1850s_-_1870s).

[image]

*"Map Showing the Telegraph Lines In Operation, Under Contract, and Contemplated to Complete the Circuit of the Globe, **1869**". Source: [HH Lloyd & Co Publishers [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Map_Showing_the_Telegraph_Lines_In_Operation,_Under_Contract,_and_Contemplated_to_Complete_the_Circuit_of_the_Globe,_1869.jpg)*

If you click on the map above, you can just read that the red lines show "Lines Constructed and in Operation".

According to the Ericsson website article *[The triumph of the telegraph](https://www.ericsson.com/en/about-us/history/communication/early-developments/the-triumph-of-the-telegraph)*,

> A Danish telegraph company combined a trans-Siberian telegraph line
>   from St Petersburg to Vladivostock with an underwater cable to China
>   and Japan. This long connection was completed in 1871.

As noted by *Henry* in his comment below, there was also a [line from Moscow to Sevastopol and Odessa](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=SnjGRDVIUL4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). This was completed in 1855, and in 1863

> The Moscow–Tbilisi (Georgia) telegraph line, 2000 km, crossing the
>   Caucasus was established.

Baku (Azerbaijan) was connected in 1868 and in 1877 Russia was second only to the US in kilometres of lines.

Comment: And that is a map concentrating on east-west lines: it does not show the the 1850s Siemens line from St. Petersburg and Moscow to Sevastopol in Crimea joining what would become the northerly and southerly trans-Asia routes